# Why does sphinx automodule work properly only on local but not on readthedocs?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

### Local Sphinx

[image: Local Sphinx]

### ReadTheDocs

[image: readthedocs]

As you can see in the ReadTheDocs image, there is no `EstraClient` imported, whereas it appears in Local Sphinx.
I used an automodule that was not listed in readthedocs. If you want to see all the codes, please visit my [GitHub](https://github.com/StawaDev/Estrapy-API/tree/main/docs)

This is my code for the `EstraClient`, and this is the first time using Sphinx, so I don't really understand Sphinx fully. Please respond if there is a solution or a problem.

```
EstraClient
============

.. automodule:: Estrapy
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

I had already included code to insert the modules in my `conf.py`, but they still did not appear in readthedocs.

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../"))
```

### Update 1

After upgrading to Python v3.10, I got an error about sphinx.errors. ConfigError: The config directory doesn't contain a conf.py file; here's the full error output.

```
Running Sphinx v5.3.0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sphinx/cmd/build.py", line 276, in build_main
    app = Sphinx(args.sourcedir, args.confdir, args.outputdir,
  File "/home/docs/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 202, in __init__
    self.config = Config.read(self.confdir, confoverrides or {}, self.tags)
  File "/home/docs/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sphinx/config.py", line 170, in read
    raise ConfigError(__("config directory doesn't contain a conf.py file (%s)") %
sphinx.errors.ConfigError: config directory doesn't contain a conf.py file (/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/estrapy-api/checkouts/latest)

Configuration error:
config directory doesn't contain a conf.py file (/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/estrapy-api/checkouts/latest)
```

And last thing my `.readthedocs.yaml` codes:

```
version: 2
sphinx:
  configuration: docs/conf.py
  builder: html

build:
  os: ubuntu-20.04
  tools:
    python: "3.10"
  commands:
    - pip install myst-parser
    - pip install sphinx-rtd-theme
    - python -m sphinx -T -E -b html -d _build/doctrees -D language=en . _build/html
```

Comment: Just for clarification, you are able to create `.rst` files locally but after commiting them to github, you are not able to view them?

Comment: Check the RTD error log, and it will tell you. My guess is that you have not configured RTD to install a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx requires your package to be installed in the environment to be able to document your package. To do that on Read the Docs, you can use the `python.install` key in the config file.

A potential working example for your case, would be similar to:

```yaml
python:
  install:
    - method: pip
      path: .
```

Read more details at: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html#python